# firewalld module in Ansible Community Package and Python3 bindings

Tags: ansible, python-3.8

I'm running Ansible Community Package 5.6 with Python3,

```
# ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook [core 2.12.4]
  config file = /opt/work/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible_collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.13 ...
  jinja version = 3.1.1
  libyaml = True
```

The following playbook,

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Open ports
    firewalld:
      zone: "public"
      port: "58080/tcp"
      permanent: true
      immediate: true
      state: enabled
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
```

failed with the error

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "icmp_block": null,
            "icmp_block_inversion": null,
            "immediate": true,
            "interface": null,
            "masquerade": null,
            "offline": null,
            "permanent": true,
            "port": "58080/tcp",
            "port_forward": null,
            "rich_rule": null,
            "service": null,
            "source": null,
            "state": "enabled",
            "target": null,
            "timeout": 0,
            "zone": "public"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Python Module not found: firewalld and its python module are required for this module, version 0.2.11 or newer required (0.3.9 or newer for offline operations)"
}
```

The [firewalld](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html) module or the ansible.posix collection is already installed by default,

```
# ansible-galaxy collection list

# /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible_collections
Collection                    Version
----------------------------- -------
amazon.aws                    2.2.0
ansible.netcommon             2.6.1
ansible.posix                 1.3.0
```

I noticed that the ansible python module and collection location (shown in the above --version) are not pointing to /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible_collections, do we need to configure these two locations?

In addition, one of the [notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html) explained that we need set ansible_python_interpreter to python3 interpreter path and install the python3 bindings. Exactly where to download and install the python3 bindings?

Comment: same issue here any answer please

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you propably have awx installed on docker and he dont have that galaxy package do this :

**1. go to main server**

```
 > docker images
```

find smt like this

```
ansible/awx    17.1.0    {here_id_of_image}   16 months ago    1.41GB
```

**2. connect to that docker image**

```
> docker run -it {here_id_of_image} bash
```

**3. Run command to install pkg**

```
> ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
```

Done now run your playbook